# How google can open something on my phone from pc?

Tags: android, google-chrome

When I look for a shop in Google on my PC I can click button "Call" and choose on which device I want to use.
Then immediately on phone opens app with number and I can start a call.

How is it possible? Websockets? Webhook that Google can use on my device?

Comment: Firebase Cloud Messaging would be a likely candidate.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.